# Get nested/related objects in a Django template

Tags: python, django

I've 2 tables (categories, articles), in my view i set:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(site=4)
```

and I can use it in my template with

```
{% for cat in categories %}
```

but the output is:

-> category 1

-> category 2

-> category 3

how can I get articles for each category like this output?

**-> category 1**

---> article 1

---> article 2

**-> category 2**

---> article 1

---> article 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends how article the model `Article` relates to `Category`, because if in your models you have an `Article` containing a e.g. `ForeignKey` to `Category`, then in your `category` instance you get a [*related object reference*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) to the artciles using `category.article_set`

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

class Article(models.Model):
    category = ForeignKey(Category) # this adds a back ref that
                                    # is by default called `article_set` 
                                    # into Category
```

You could do:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category }}
    {% for article in category.article_set.all %}
        {{ article }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In the view you can pass only the `categories` queryset like you already did, then from the template you can access the articles via the `category.article_set` reference, so no change is required in your view function

Comment: but _set is default or I need to edit it? Because i get this error: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'category.article_set.all()'

Comment: Please try without the `()`, just `category.article_set.all`, I may have had a typo when I first typed the answer

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/